# setTimeout event for this function but it is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I cannot get the setTimeout event working for this code.  I have tried this in various configurations but no luck.  Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

I am trying to print out the "lorem ipsum" one charachter at a time but I want to wait a few seconds before it begins.

```
setTimeout(
    (function ($) {
        $.fn.writeText = function (content) {
            var contentArray = content.split(""),
                current = 0,
                elem = this;
            setInterval(function () {
                if (current < contentArray.length) {
                    elem.text(elem.text() + contentArray[current++]);
                }
            }, 40);
        };
    })(jQuery);

    $("#description").writeText("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate.");
, 3000);
```

RESOLUTION:

Here is the working code.  The problem was that the entire plugin was wrapped in the timeout.  The resolution was to only wrap the line that implemented the plugin.  Thank you @adeno for the answer!

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.writeText = function (content) {
        var contentArray = content.split(""),
            current = 0,
            elem = this;
        setInterval(function () {
            if (current < contentArray.length) {
                elem.text(elem.text() + contentArray[current++]);
            }
        }, 40);
    };
})(jQuery);

setTimeout(function () {
    $("#description").writeText("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,     sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate.");
}, 3000);
```

Comment: _but no luck._ - What does that mean? What does the console say?

Comment: It means that I cannot get this to work.  Do you know what is wrong?

Comment: You can't wrap a jQuery plugin in a setTimeout, and what would even be the point ?

Comment: "not getting it to work" is not a good description. The questions we care about are: "what error message do you see?"; "what were you expecting? and what do you get instead?". the code you posted is not even syntactically valid, so your console should so you the parser's error message.

Comment: You're not stopping the `setInterval()` anywhere, so your code will run until you leave/refresh the page.

Comment: Im sorry, I am a new coder. I was expecting to print out the lorem ipsum one character at a time with a setTimeout of 3 seconds. What I got was nothing executed at all.  I was not aware that you could not wrap the Jquery in a setTimeout.  What would be a good way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3):

setTimeout has the following signature:

```
setTimeout(function, timeout_in_ms);
```

In your code, you have:

```
setTimeout(
    statement;
    statement;
    statement;
    , timeout_in_ms
);
```

So it's not even syntactically correct

Comment: Ok, thanks!  So how would I achieve the setTimeout effect for this?

Comment: Wrap all the statements in another function.

Comment: @mc0117 It would also help if you could explain what the code is supposed to accomplish.

Comment: I am trying to print out the "lorem ipsum" one charachter at a time but I want to wait a few seconds before it begins.

Comment: @mc0117 - wrapping the entire plugin in a timeout is ***not*** the way to do that. wrap just the line where you implement the plugin, i.e. the last one in your code.